# Is there a way to create a custom type for a list declaration?

Tags: python

I have a class type 'person' and I would like to make this class be the type for a newly crated list instead of the basic types like 'int', 'string' and such.

I tried doing a code block like this:

`person p = [] * 100`

Unlike some other programming languages like Java or C++, placing a data type before the variable leads to an error, so this approach is not workable.

Comment: What were you expecting `[] * 100` to do?  That's the same thing as just `[]`.

Comment: your question doesn't really make sense. Python is a dynamic programming language, the built-in containers don't have a "type". Python *doesn't have variable declarations either*

Comment: You should first work through the Python tutorial https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ .

Answer (score 0):

Python is a dynamically typed language, so you can't really type anything. However, you can do what they call "type hinting", which will help with LSP/linters/static checkers.

PEP 484:
https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/

To type hint a list of `person` instances in Python 3.9+:

```py
Class Person:
   pass

inst1 = Person()
inst2 = Person()

p: list[Person] = [inst1, inst2]
```

Comment: Contrary to what your answer claims, `p = Person([])` does not "make a list of type `person`".

Comment: @user2357112 You're right, that wasn't great wording. I've edited it.

Comment: The type hint for an empty list of `Person` is: `p: list[Person] = []`

Comment: @jwhitlock I don't think they are trying to make a list of `Person`. I think they are trying to make the `Person` class be a specific type of list.

Comment: Since they mentioned Java and C++, I suspect @John Murphy is thinking of an array in those languages, a collection of homogeneous elements (all the same type), often of a fixed size, and contiguous in memory. A Python `list` is not fixed size, is heterogeneous (can contain mixed types including primitives), and makes no memory promises. You can use type annotations to signal that a list is homogeneous, and adding a different type is a type error.

Comment: @CageFury, I think    p = person([]) is trying to pass an empty list into the constructor of the class person. And I am looking for a list collection whose variable that holds it is of type person.

Comment: @jwhitlock, I am getting this error:  'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @CageFury, there seems to be code missing. So you do pass a list into the constructor. Now what?

Comment: @JohnMurphy I thought you were trying to create a custom list class, not just type hint a list that contains instances of a specific class. See my edit above.

Comment: @jwhitlock A 'not scriptable' error on this type hint probably means you're on a version of Python before 3.5.

Comment: @CageFury, that looks a lot like a FIXED list. Only 2 indexes. I am looking for a undetermined usage of indexes, so a list with 100 elements would be good here. Hence, " person p = [] * 100 "   in the problem post above.

Comment: @JohnMurphy There is no such thing as a fixed list in Python, at least not by default. Lists are objects around actual C arrays that are automatically extended or re-allocated as needed. To extend a list, you call the objects `append` method, e.g. `mylist.append(newinst)`.

Comment: @JohnMurphy - the type hint `p: list[Person] = []` is for Python 3.9 and later. In Python 3.8 and earlier you'll need `from typing import List`, and `p: List[Person] = []`. See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html for more. 

However, you may want to start with a tutorial focused on learning Python for experienced devs. See https://diveintopython3.net/ or a guide based on your experience.